# AWS: Specified ConcurrentExecutions for function decreases account's UnreservedConcurrentExecution below its minimum value of [10]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-service-quotas

I keep getting this error when deploying a laravel project with GitHub actions

```
==> Updating Function Configurations

     Deployment Failed 

    AWS: Specified ConcurrentExecutions for function decreases account's UnreservedConcurrentExecution below its minimum value of [10].

 23613KB/23613KB [============================] 100% (< 1 sec remaining)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 6):

This means you have reserved more capacity that your account/regional maximum.  By default, Lambda allows you to have 1000 concurrent lambda executions in each region.  When you create a function, you can specify (this is optional) to reserve a portion of that concurrency for your function.  You can't reserve 100% of your account/region's concurrency or lambdas without this setting wouldn't be able to run, that is what this error is saying.

You have 2 options:

1. Reduce the amount of reserved/provisioned concurrency you have for this and your other lambda functions in region (or just don't specify any reserved/provisioned concurrency if this is just an experiment).
2. Request a limit increase with AWS Support.

Some reading material:

- What is reserved concurrency: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html
- Default limits (including concurrency) for Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html
- How to request an increase of concurrency limits: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase/

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error on a new (empty) AWS account with only 1 lambda function.
I followed this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/request-quota-increase.html and I noticed that my "Concurrent executions" service quota was set to 10, and not the default 1,000.

So I requested an increase from the service quotas page
https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this section in `AWS Console`:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home

[image]